Google Maps API Key is Not Working When Application Restrictions Set to android flutter only
Hi I have a google key for maps. When I have it unrestricted it works as intended but when I add in android restriction with my pagackage and debug SHA1 key it rejects it. I have no idea what is wrong. It does work PERFECTLY fine unrestricted.
The only solution I have found is by forcing the SHA keys in to the header of the HTTPS requests. via:
main.dart
    final String buildCert = await platform.invokeMethod('getBuildCert');

kotlin MainActivity
    private fun getBuildCert(): String? {
        try {
            val packageInfo: PackageInfo = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
            } else {
                packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            }

            val signatures = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                packageInfo.signingInfo.apkContentsSigners
            } else {
                packageInfo.signatures
            }

            for (signature in signatures) {
                val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
                digest.update(signature.toByteArray())
                val hashText = digest.digest()
                return bytesToHex(hashText)
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("SHA1", "Package not found", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            Log.e("SHA1", "SHA-1 algorithm not found", e)
        }

        return null
    }



I have create a new key from scratch
Tried on physical and emulator on a few different PCs and physical devices
I tried to change the package name
I have verified the SHA and package name multiple times and looked in my proj to see if there were reminent of old package names.

Google Console

KeyTool

This is my android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml and
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mazaar.frontend">
    <application
        android:label="Mazaar"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <!-- Google Maps API Key configuration -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${googleMapsApiKey}" />
        
        <!-- MainActivity configuration -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true">
            <!-- Theme for Flutter UI initialization -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Main launcher intent filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Intent filters for handling HTTP and HTTPS schemes -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Required for Flutter plugins -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <!-- Queries for internet browsers (Android 11 and above) -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.mazaar.frontend"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mazaar.frontend"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        def googleMapsApiKey = properties.getProperty('googleMapsApiKey')
        println "Google Maps API Key: ${googleMapsApiKey}"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            googleMapsApiKey: googleMapsApiKey,
            applicationName: "android.app.Application"
        ]

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

Local.properties
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\jarvis\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\jarvis\\Documents\\Jump\\flutter_sdk\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
googleMapsApiKey=AIzaSyB...


Could you please create a support case in the Google Cloud Console to open a personalized communication channel?
